# How do I set Java's min and max heap size through environment variables?

Tags: java, environment-variables, heap-memory

How do I set Java's min and max heap size through environment variables?

I know that the heap sizes can be set when launching java, but I would like to have this adjusted through environment variables on my server.

Comment: The accepted answer is out of date and does not apply anymore.  Refer to @Gauthier's answer if you end up here

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can't do it using environment variables directly. You need to use the set of "non standard" options that are passed to the java command. Run: java -X for details. The options you're looking for are -Xmx and -Xms (this is "initial" heap size, so probably what you're looking for.)

Some products like Ant or Tomcat might come with a batch script that looks for the JAVA_OPTS environment variable, but it's not part of the Java runtime.  If you are using one of those products, you may be able to set the variable like:

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx256m"
```

You can also take this approach with your own command line like:

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx256m"  
java ${JAVA_OPTS} MyClass
```

Comment: The `JAVA_OPTS` technique is also used by the scripts generated by the maven appassemble plugin.

Comment: as @neves mentioned in a comment below this has changed in java 7 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/envvars.html). 
you can use JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS (see link and answers below)

Answer (score 78):

If you want any `java` process, not just ant or Tomcat, to pick up options like `-Xmx` use the environment variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS`.

In bash: `export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1g"`

Comment: Perfect, this works great and saved me a lot of looking.

Comment: In Windows: `set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx1g`

To make it permanent, [make a new environment variable](http://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10) `_JAVA_OPTIONS` and set it to `-Xmx1g`

Comment: See also [Difference between _JAVA_OPTIONS and JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327620/difference-between-java-options-java-tool-options-and-java-opts/40736821#40736821)

Answer (score 39):

You can use `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`.

Example:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m
```

It has been mentioned in some comments, and in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40736904/2041863).

The OP's question is quite old, but as it is the first google result for the question, I thought i would add the answer here for clarity's sake.

Comment: Should be the new accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

Actually, there is a way to set global defaults for Sun's JVM via environment variables.

See [How to set a java system property so that it is effective whenever I start JVM without adding it to the command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577437/how-to-set-a-java-system-property-so-that-it-is-effective-whenever-i-start-jvm-w).

Answer (score 9):

You can't do it using environment variables. It's done via "non standard" options. Run: `java -X` for details. The options you're looking for are `-Xmx` and `-Xms` (this is "initial" heap size, so probably what you're looking for.)

Comment: It looks it changed in Java 7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/envvars.html

Answer (score 4):

I think your only option is to wrap java in a script that substitutes the environment variables into the command line

Answer (score 3):

A couple of notes:

1. Apache ant doesn't know anything about JAVA_OPTS, while Tomcat's startup scripts do. For Apache ant, use ANT_OPTS to affect the environment for the JVM that runs /ant/, but not for the things that ant might launch.
2. The maximum heap size you can set depends entirely on the environment: for most 32-bit systems, the maximum amount of heap space you can request, regardless of available memory, is in the 2GiB range. The largest heap on a 64-bit system is "really big". Also, you are practically limited by physical memory as well, since the heap is managed by the JVM and you don't want a lot of swapping going on to the disk.
3. For server environments, you typically want to set -Xms and -Xmx to the same value: this will fix the size of the heap at a certain size and the garbage collector has less work to do because the heap will never have to be re-sized.