# How to handle java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java

I am running a makefile and after a while I get the following error:

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

I am wondering whether there is a command that allows me to increase
the Java Heap Space. I dont want to change the makefile itself, so I need
some kind of "global" command that allows me to reset the Java Heap Space.

Many thanks,
Patrick

EDIT: Thanks for your answers. But I am looking for a more global command, that
allows me to specify to set the Heap space once and for all like:

SET JAVA_HEAP_SPACE = 5GB

Thanks

Comment: Similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417152/how-do-i-set-javas-min-and-max-heap-size-through-environment-variables

Comment: It is exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417152/how-do-i-set-javas-min-and-max-heap-size-through-environment-variables

Comment: Unless you a 32-bit windows version, it should have a maximum of 1/4 of your memory.  If this is not enough, you have something strange in your build as even the entire OpenJDK source can be compiled with default settings.  BTW: Maven is a much better choice than make for Java builds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can set java heap space from command line: `java -Xmx1600m program` Now your heap space is 1600 MB.(Assuming your hardware can already afford 1600MB.)
- For Windows platforms, you can set it from ***Java Runtime Environment
  Settings*** as well.  Follow *Control Panel => Programs => Java*. Navigate to Java tab. View Java Runtime Environment Settings. Add `-Xmx1600m` to Runtime Parameters. Save and go on.
- For Linux platforms, you can launch Control Panel and edit runtime parameters. It can be run from something like `/usr/j2se/jre/bin/ControlPanel`. Find your own directory. Read here please: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/jcp.html

Comment: Yes, but this implies that I have to change the makefile, where the java build is actually executed. I do not want to this, I wonder whether I can set the Heap for ALL executed Java programs....

Comment: Unfortunately I am on Linux, using the command line. Is there something similar available as in Windows?

Comment: @Patrick I've added a solution for Linux too. check it again please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command :

```
java -Xms64m -Xmx256m ClassName
Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
```

In this example, initial heap size set to 64MB and maximum heap size is set to 256MB. For more information check [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jvm-java-increase-heap-size-setting-heap-size-jvm-heap/).

Answer (score 0):

question is not very clear However you should look at -Xmx flag as the JVM startup parameter to make more memory available to your application. Please read [here](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/performance/jvm-tuning.xtp) for more on this. You should also do profiling of you Java application and see where the most of the available memory is being consumed. You can make use of JProfiler (just google about the tools to profile you Java application) to profile and see the statistics about which part of application is consuming more systems resource.