# is there any command option in java to set environment variable?

Tags: java, environment-variables

I'm working on Java.

is there any option in the `"java"` to set the user defined environmental variable to the executable that we will execute using `"java"` command.
e.g. we have one option -XX:+AllowUserSignalHandlers.

Comment: Your question is not that clear. Do you want to set environment variable for the process that your launching? In any case  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417152/how-do-i-set-javas-min-and-max-heap-size-through-environment-variables for some useful answers

Answer (score 0):

You can set tuning parameter to JVM at the start of the program itself.

ex -

```
java -XMS50m -XX:+AllowUserSignalHandlers Test.class
```

Once jvm is started you can not set environment variables but you can view them `System.genEnv` it retuns an unmodifiable string map view of the current system environment.

If you are creating a new process then you can set environment variables using `ProcessBuilder.environment`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no environment variable that java.exe parses and used to set command line arguments.

You have to write a program/script that would process your custom environment variable and then pass to actual java program.