# Error "java heap size" in Eclipse Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, heap-size, graphical-layout-editor

When I'm using the graphical layout editor after 5-10 minutes of working I get the error "java heap size". I tried to increase size in eclipse.ini:
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
But it doesn't helped. Please tell me who encountered this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Keep increasing it.  I had to give it a couple of gigs for my app to compile

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same problem. Can't seem to keep eclipse open for more than 5 minutes in graphical layout mode.

Answer (score 2):

Your eclipse.ini settings will take effect only if you change following:

Run -> External Tools -> External Tool

Configurations. go to configuration that u use, under jre tab -select option

Run in same JRE in workspace.

For more info on the topic have a look at this link. [What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

If sometimes you get this error and smetimes doesn't then It might happens because RAM is being used by other processes which require large memory. Close all the other Applications/processes and try to start/load the eclipse. It works.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this on the command line before running eclipse so that eclipse has more mem: [How do I set Java's min and max heap size through environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417152/how-do-i-set-javas-min-and-max-heap-size-through-environment-variables)