# Issue with java heap space in android?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have attached four libraries in my project, but when I try to run this project, that time Eclipse show error dialog with error "Problem occurred with heap space". So what I have to do? Any idea related to this helps.

Comment: **Eclipse** has a problem with the Heap on **your** machine. Not related to android.

Comment: is Eclipse close down ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393215/error-java-heap-size-in-eclipse-android/15393350#15393350

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your eclipse, installation folder find the `eclipse.ini`

[image]

and edit this file to increase size of heap as shown following

```
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

to something more like

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Edit :

Your eclipse.ini settings change will take effect only if you change following:

Run -> External Tools -> External ToolConfigurations.

go to configuration that u use, under jre tab -select option

Run in same JRE in workspace.

For more info on the topic have a look at this link.

[What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse)

Comment: which Eclipse IDE version you are using ??

Comment: Is is your system RAM less or something ? Accordingly specify Heap Size

Comment: my system ram: 4 GB, processor core i3, and os: windows 8 - 64 bit

Comment: @HirenPatel glad the edit helped. Credit to ajduke for posting the snapshot

Comment: @Raghunandan good work at the end of answer, thanks !! (+1`d in other post answer which link you mentioned )