# eclipse with Android sdk, ERROR: Java heap space

Tags: java, android, eclipse, configuration

So lately I'm having a problem while working in my apps inside eclipse the next message shows up while working with xml files:

```
ERROR: 'Java heap space'
```

I have read an try increasing inside the eclipse.ini file the:

```
-vmargs
-Xmx40m
-Xmx512m
```

to:

```
-vmargs
-Xmx512m
-Xmx1024m
```

but it will work for a while than after and hour or so it will give me the same error, I'm working in a MacBook air with 4gb ram.
I have
Eclipse SDK
Version: 3.7.2
Build id: M20120208-0800
and I just updated it, so I don't know if that is why is acting up this way, this is how my eclipse.ini looks right now:

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.101.v20120109-1504
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xmx512m
-Xmx1024m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

what else can I do to fix this? any help is really appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

In Run->Run Configuration find the Name of the class you have been running, select it, click the Arguments tab then add:

```
  -Xms512M -Xmx1524M
```

to the VM Arguments section

Few useful links

[What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse)

[Error "java heap size" in Eclipse Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393215/error-java-heap-size-in-eclipse-android/15393350#15393350)

Edit:

Your eclipse.ini settings will take effect only if you change following:

Run -> External Tools -> External Tool

Configurations. go to configuration that u use, under jre tab -select option

Run in same JRE in workspace.

Comment: I have try to follow your instructions but can't find a Arguments tab....I can see a list of my apps, when I choose the one I'm working on there are 3 tabs to the right Android, Target and Common am I missing something? thanks

Comment: I'm doing Run-External tool-External Tool Conf.... but in there I can see in the left: Ant Build, API use report and Program

Comment: @zvzej http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse. you can click the ant build too. go to jre there you will find the option run in same jre workspace

Comment: @zvzej try whats mentioned in the above comment and let me know

Comment: I'm sorry its going to take me a while, now eclipse is not building my jar files in any application!!!

Comment: the vote you see is mine I did it las Friday when you helped me.

Comment: Is there another way or the best way to increase the java heap space? the problem has return and I cannot work in eclipse! please help me.

Comment: repeat the above steps or reinstall eclipse by downloading a fresh copy

Comment: I already try the steps with out luck, do you really think reinstalling a new copy of eclipse will work?

Comment: @zvzej try it out. there is no harm in trying. keep the old one and isntall it on a different drive.

Comment: I tried the 
Run -> External Tools -> External Tool Configurations
-> New -> jre Tab -> select "run in same jre workspace" as mention by Raghunandan.
It seem like my application do not have the same error and run faster but on the other hand is still quite slow (just a bit faster than before). 
@zvzej: Hope that it will help for you as I have similar spec as yours.

Comment: there is no such option available in Eclipse, this answer is false.

Comment: @AndroidHacker Are you sure??. I answered this in 2013 @ that time this answered worked and i checked this before posting it as an answer. It might still work. But android studio is the official IDE for android. Better switch to android studio.

Comment: If you provide me the way to get rid of heap space error in eclipse, that will be good, My current IDE is Eclipse only, not able to switch. thank u. @Raghunandan

Comment: @AndroidHacker then its not late to switch. All samples from google also have gradle build. You should switch ASAP. As for the solution i cannot try this again cause i do not have eclipse installed on my system now.