# java heap space eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, memory-leaks

I am using eclipse for about a year now, and I was very pleased with the programming environment. I constantly increased the amount of plugins and extensions.

The problem is that I apparently use too much heap space. When I start up eclipse, it gives a bunch of errors and its basically advising me to shut down.

Example:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Decoration Calculation".
Java heap space
```

When I then run the Memory analyzer, it gives the following report:

```
One instance of "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk" loaded by
"com.android.ide.eclipse.adt" occupies 36,164,216 (47.59%) bytes. The memory is 
accumulated in one instance of "com.android.ide.common.resources.FrameworkResources" 
loaded by "com.android.ide.eclipse.base".
```

Question 1: Is this error caused by my Android app project or by the Android SDK plugin?
Question 2: Is there an easy fix to this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Ronald

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741680/eclipse-with-android-sdk-error-java-heap-space/16742236#16742236. try this if it helps

Comment: Maybe remove unused plugins it will make Eclipse run faster, but answer above is also good.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=139131

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz - Are you standing on your head or something?  Answers are *below* on my browser.  :-)

Comment: Removed the "gentlemen" salutation since I believe that there may be some female developers in this world!

Answer (score 0):

Try allocating more heap space to eclipse.
Go to eclipse.ini file in the eclipse directory and change heap space parameter.

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
```

Make sure to restart eclipse once you have make this change.

See if it works.

Comment: I am not a heap space or a memory leak expert, but extending the available memory does not sound like a solution to me.