# Java Heap in Eclipse keeps growing no matter what I do

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I'm running the latest version of the Android SDK/Eclipse IDE package on Mac OS Mountain Lion.  Previously I have not had any issues like this, but with the most recent project I've started building I am getting a Java Heap error on activity_main.xml.  I haven't done anything except add some images and modify the XML file.  Otherwise my project is literally out of the box defaults.  I've tried increasing the size of Eclipse's memory in the INI file to no avail.  I tried deleting my project and recreating from scratch but the issue still persists.  The error pops up as soon as I open Eclipse and it prevents me from doing/clicking on ANYTHING. It consumes the available memory FAST and makes my whole system slow down.  I'm not even running the application.  I'm just trying to EDIT it. Why is this happening?  How can I stop it?

Here is my layout file, it's nothing special:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/featured"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="Featured Model"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/featuredmodel" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/hotlist"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="Hot List"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/hotlist" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/special"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="Special Offer"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/specialoffer" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/service"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="Book Service"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/bookservice" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/video"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="Video Experience"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/videoexperience" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/about"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="About Us"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/aboutus" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mercedes-Benz Oakville"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="The Best Place to Buy Your New Vehicle"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="top|right"
            android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="Mark Message"
            android:src="@drawable/markmessage" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="App Info"
            android:src="@drawable/info" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/help"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="Help"
            android:src="@drawable/helpicon" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="Phone"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/phone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="Share"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/share" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="Mail"
            android:src="@drawable/mail" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom|right"
            android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="Logo"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What about InelliJ or AndroidStudio?

Comment: possible duplicate of [eclipse with Android sdk, ERROR: Java heap space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741680/eclipse-with-android-sdk-error-java-heap-space)

Comment: Well, I have no idea what's wrong with Eclipse. I migrated my project to IntelliJ and everything works fine now.