# Heap space error while working with xml

Tags: android, heap-memory

While I am working in my app I get the error about heap space. I would like to mention that application is really small, and I am getting this error while I am moving editText fields in one of the xml files. How can I find out where is a problem?

Here is my Eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Declipse.buildId=v21.0.1-543035
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741680/eclipse-with-android-sdk-error-java-heap-space/16742236#16742236. check this

Comment: sorry but that link doesn't help much. I am interested why it is taking so much memory. It is not normal behavior to do that when I move editText field

Comment: You need a memory analyzer tool mat http://www.eclipse.org/mat/. and check this  assuming you are talking about memory managment of your android app. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk. and ignore both links if it does not help