# Eclipse has stopped working and won't start anymore

Tags: java, android, eclipse, crash

Eclipse gave me an error which said

```
GC overhead limit exeeded
```

I know this is related to garbage collection and I had to shut down eclipse because nothing was working. Now when I start it it shows a splashscreen with the dialogue box of choosing workspace. I choose ok and eclipse shut down. It also initially told me to see the error report in a log file: here is the full file, it's an SWT error, any solutions to this????

```
!SESSION 2013-08-18 02:46:09.721 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=v22.0.5-757759
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-08-18 02:46:47.319
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.createHandle(Composite.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.createHandle(Decorations.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.createHandle(Shell.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.createWidget(Scrollable.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.createWidget(Decorations.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.createShell(Window.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.prompt(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.promptForWorkspace(IDEApplication.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.checkInstanceLocation(IDEApplication.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try Changing(Increase) Memory Configuration on eclipse.ini :

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

More information on : [How to fix GC overhead limit exceeded in Eclipse](http://docs.oseems.com/general/application/eclipse/fix-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

Comment: How will this affect the app that I am making? Shouldnt I try to work around this because ultimately the app running on the phone shouldnt take up too much resources.

Comment: with changing PermSize just increase eclipse memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so here's a temporary fix I've found to this:

On the splashscreen box where it says Workspace, change the workspace to something else.

I've looked at other solutions and they did not work for me at all and I'm not going to reinstall Eclipse all over again if I can help it !

The intuitive sense of the problem that I have is that when I shut down eclipse the error causing task was still running. Some insight might be found here as well: http://www.metod.si/job-found-still-running-after-platform-shutdown-eclipse/ , although it was not the same error.

Au revoir, and I'll post any updates if I have them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741680/eclipse-with-android-sdk-error-java-heap-space/16742236#16742236 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471194/unable-to-execute-dex-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded. try the links should help you

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse MARS and had a large JSON file open when this started happening.  The UI was not fully rendered and was unresponsive.  I had to kill it with the Task Manager.  The subject error was found in the .log file.
I had to locate the workbench.xmi file under the workspace .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench folder and delete the children element that was referencing the open file.  After saving that I could restart Eclipse.