# Quickblox library java heap space

Tags: android, quickblox

i imported the example https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat and works, but when i create new project an copy the library, the eclipse no respond and close with message java heap space. After that, i clean the sample that was working and stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have famous problem. There are many issues opened on it: [eclipse with Android sdk, ERROR: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741680/eclipse-with-android-sdk-error-java-heap-space) .
Or [Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943712/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-java-heap-space). And here : http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space/

Comment: i try the solutions, change the VM arguments -Xms512M -Xmx512M (if i try with -Xmx1024 i have the problem faled to create the Java VM) and no change, the problem persists