# Java heap Space error in Eclipse again and again

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am getting `Java Heap Space` error in `Eclipse` again and again so I change `config` of `Eclipse`. But still no effect. I am not able to work properly because of it. 
Please help me to solve this issue.
**Config:**

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSi512M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersionXms512m
-=1.7-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
```

Comment: There are several broken lines in your config file: `--launcher.XXMaxPermSi512M` or `-=1.7-Xmx1024m` (with "broken" I mean syntax errors). And why set _max perm size_ to 1024M? That's too much.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, I have just changed size, nothing else. If you are sure then tell me what to do changes ?

Comment: You first should repair your config file and learn what memory options the JVM has. You didn't set any, you only set the max perm size.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off Lint and problem solved. You can do it by `Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking ->` then untick checkboxes at top of page

Comment: Are you sure that it is best solution ? Bcz after that, It wont check for errors.

Comment: where does your eclipse crashes??On XML editor or does it not start at all..PS Use Android Studio and there would have been no issue at all in the first place

Comment: When I run any project, it starts for 2-3 times but then error.

Comment: Try out the edit answer by Raghunandan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741680/eclipse-with-android-sdk-error-java-heap-space/16742236#16742236