# Issues in run Eclipse project of android Heap size exceeds

Tags: android, eclipse, heap-memory, heap-size

Hello friends i m running android project in **eclipse JUNO** , when i run project it will give error message every time like below image

[image]

Any idea how can i solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [eclipse with Android sdk, ERROR: Java heap space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741680/eclipse-with-android-sdk-error-java-heap-space)

Comment: Anything specific about this in LogCat