# V-Modell XT installer: "installation failed" error / missing proxy settings and how to provide them

Tags: java, proxy, project-management

downloadable from here: http://www.cio.bund.de/DE/Architekturen-und-Standards/V-Modell-XT/vmodell_xt_node.html

nothing is written to the log (they are empty ... in tmp folder or installation folder if existing) and no further details are given.

Comment: should be moved to more appropriate site: http://pm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem for my environment were missing http proxy settings.
Solved via providing them via system properties (`https.proxy*` variables are auto-set to the same values):

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=<your-proxy-host>
-Dhttp.proxyPort=<your-proxy-port>
-Dno_proxy=<some-internal-ip1>;<some-internal-ip-range.*>;<some-dns-name-pattern, e.g. '*.mycomp.*'>
```

an even nicer way to provide such proxy settings is by using some system environment variable named `JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS` which applies these proxies by default to all kinds of your Java executables by default since JRE 1.7:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/envvars.html

also discussed and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12723083/1915920

e.g. in Windows just set it up under

```
-> Start Menu 
-> type: "environment variables ..." and click on the right app
-> add as system or user variable
```

Comment: I can't create the tags (yet) `v-modell-xt` and `v-model-xt`. It's said to be roughly equivalent to the `Prince 2` standard and is the officially enforced methodology for public government IT projects. So it would make sense to do this. See also http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-Modell_%28Entwicklungsstandard%29 or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-Model.